# How did the Fairchild Channel F provide a 2K frame buffer?

Tags: memory, chip, game-consoles

The Fairchild Channel F, released in 1976, was the first modern game console, in the sense of being the first one to accept games as software, rather than just modular configuration switches.

Looking at the specifications, the thing that jumps out at me is that (in addition to 64 bytes of working RAM) it has a 2K write-only frame buffer:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_Channel_F#Technical_specifications

The above both directly describes the frame buffer, and gives the resolution, from one which one can verify that 128x64x2/8 = 2K.

This is particularly notable in that the Atari 2600, released a year later, did *not* have a frame buffer.

How did Fairchild provide such a thing within the technology and cost constraints?

Looking at the ads in the back of Byte magazine for December 1976, I don't see any chips advertised for any price that could easily provide that. There are e.g. 256x4 static rams advertised, but it would take 16 of those to make 2K, which would surely blow the budget, and looking at photographs of the circuit board, I don't see any large arrays of identical chips.

So how did they do it? What chips were used?

Comment: [2K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2K_resolution) frame buffer? Quite ahead of its time, it seems.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image: Channel F schematics page 2/3 : Video]

ChannelF uses 4 MK4096 4k * 1bit chips (4 middle-left rectangles in the schematics).

The framebuffer is write-only, the CPU cannot directly access it through memory accesses. The CPU has no address bus anyway, just IO ports.

Framebuffer updates are performed by setting the line, column and colour of the pixel to change on IO ports (BTW, these IO ports are shared with the joysticks to reduce cost).

Comment: Wait, the CPU doesn't have an address bus? How does that work? :O

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic Instructions are fed from a separate chip containing those.

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic It's quite special, read the Channel F CPU "F8", Fairchild 3850 manual. The instruction set is... odd, the CPU has no address bus, it doesn't have a "Program Counter" inside nor index registers. these registers are instead in the ROM memory chips.

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic: If one imagines a system as having one RAM, one ROM, and one CPU, the cost of integrating a counter and a bit of other logic into the RAM and ROM chip would be less than the cost of the extra lead wires needed to support an address bus, especially if one considers that the CPU itself wouldn't need that circuitry. Pretty soon, people realized that having microprocessors as all-in-one units which combine address generation with everything else had a lot of advantages, but before the division wasn't so sharp.  If one looks at the CDP1802 processor and thinks about the way...

Comment: ...instructions work, it feels like the accumulator (D register) lives in another universe from the 16 numbered registers R0-R15, and it turns out there's a reason for that.  Early versions of the design put address generation as well as the storage for the 16 registers in a separate chip from everything else.

Comment: That's super interesting. I had no idea. Thanks man!

Comment: @supercat  F8 !!!! - "Weave a circle round him thrice, and close your eyes with holy dread .... !" --> I've played with quite a few processors from the dawn of time, but the F8 was the strangest, if not perhaps the most abominable :-). (6800, 8080, 6502, Z80, ST6, Z8,  F8, SC/MP, MC14500, 8008, PIC, AVR, ... (most in the flesh, some only on paper).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Have you looked at the 1802 instruction set?  Some neat and clever stuff there, some that made me scratch my head until I learned of the two-chip origins, and some that I still find weird.  The concept behind interrupt handling is neat, but seems a bit over-complicated.  I would think it would have been simpler to have a couple of interrupt control bits that either cause the P register to be ignored, using a hard-coded value of 0 (DMA should have used 1) instead, and either allow or disallow the interrupt pin from hitting that first bit, thus avoiding any need to have...

Comment: ...hardware save the P register state.  Of course, this won't mean anything unless/until you read about the 1802 instruction set.

Comment: I did not do anything serious with the 1802. When I was using a 6802 my research-room-mate had used an 1802 for some tasks and we discussed various aspects of it.  That was about 45 years ago, so I've no doubt forgotten anything I never learned :-).  I actively used 6802 a lot, 8080 a little, Z8 a reasonable amount, ST6 also,  Z80 some, 6502 only to do some Apple II machine language device interfacing, AVR various, ... .

Answer (score 10):

> The Fairchild Channel F, released in 1976, was the first modern game console

Let's restrict that to first successful in large numbers.

> Looking at the specifications, the thing that jumps out at me is that (in addition to 64 bytes of working RAM) it has a 2K write-only frame buffer.

Picture has to go somewhere.

> This is particularly notable in that the Atari 2600, released a year later, did not have a frame buffer.

The 2600 was intended to be a cost cutter. Saving four DRAM chips goes a great length toward that goal.

> I don't see any chips advertised for any price that could easily provide that.

The Channel F design uses four [Mostek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostek) MK4027 (or MK4015), a 1976 introduced improved version of the all classic 1973 MK4096 DRAM, each providing 4 KiBit for a total of 2x8 KiBit or 2 KiByte.

Comment: Wikipedia says the Channel F was first with a microprocessor and first with ROM cartridges, but sold less than some of its predecessors, so I don't see your first line. The Atari 2600 was more expensive at launch than the Channel F, and demonstrated that the picture did not, in fact, have to go anywhere besides direct to the screen.

Comment: @prosfilaes Well, if you read history at whole, you'll note that the Channel F was based on a prior 8080 design Fairchild bought and modified for their own CPU. Next, price difference was about 10%, not exactly a lot. More important, cost cutting is quite different from price cutting. Last, what relevance has it how a picture is made?

Comment: Prototypes aren't usually counted. I don't know what you mean by "a cost cutter" then, as every single commercial product is designed to reduce construction cost to increase profit. Lastly, "Picture has to go somewhere." seems to be a bit snarky, since at the same time your answer admits the Atari 2600 didn't need the DRAM.

Comment: It's a bit snarky, but I hesitate to call it wrong.  I mean, I guess in the CRT days you could sync on the movement of the electron gun and just sort of send the right voltage at the right time to get the result you want for each pixel.  Presumably modern displays/interface protocols more-or-less require the use of a framebuffer though? 8.3 million pixels gotta go somewhere.

Comment: @aroth That's how the Atari 2600 works, so that was possible for the Channel F.

Comment: @prosfilaes Cost cutting simply means exactly that. The VCS design was made to not use a traditional setup with a video controller and video RAM to lower production cost, so break even would come at moderate sales numbers and yield optional higher profit on the long run. Is that approach so unusual? And that's all that line states. Also, why should channel F have gone the same way? Commodore did as well not build the C64 like a ZX80, despite that way being known. Somehow your comments make no sense.

Comment: @Raffzahn You said "cost cutter", not "cost cutting", and I don't see any evidence that cost cutting was more of a factor in the Atari 2600 than in the Channel F. I don't know why Channel F should have gone the same way, but your answer bluntly says "Picture has to go somewhere." when in fact it doesn't. All my comments are in response to your answer and seem to make plenty of sense in that context.

Comment: @prosfilaes It's helpful to read a sentence before argue about words. The answer why is clear, they wanted to have a full screen memory- like any other system including the very   one you're using right now. You may want to argue with those manufacturers as well if you think it's a bad idea. The 2600 design trades RAM usage for increased ROM code as well as limiting possible display content at the same time. That's fine as long as sufficient for the games in mind (Pong).

Comment: @raffzahn It's helpful to clarify your answer rather than writing extensive arguments in the comments.

Answer (score 10):

There were two main kinds of memory chips in 1976: dynamic RAM and static RAM.  A static RAM used two active transistors and two passive pullups to hold each bit, plus two more active transistors to support reading and writing (one is needed to write ones, and one is needed to write zerores; either or both can be used for reading).  Dynamic RAM, by contrast, held each bit in a combination of a transistor and a capacitor.  A dynamic RAM chip could hold about four times as many bits as a static RAM of the same physical dimension, but would generally require more circuitry to interface it, including circuitry to ensure that no row goes more than a millisecond or so without at least one bit on it being accessed.

The RIOT chip on the Atari 2600 had 1024 bits (128x8) of RAM internally, which is 1/4 as much as each of the chips used on the Fairchild.  While using four DRAM chips may have been "generous", I think the 128x64 resolution in four colors was probably perceived as the minimum anyone would want in a video game system (though the CDP 1802-based RCA Studio II had a horizontal resolution of 64 pixels black an white, and was typically used with a vertical resolution of 32 pixels, using half of its 512x8 static RAM as a display buffer).

While 2K of even DRAM was a fair chunk of memory, the fact that the Fairchild could use DRAM rather than SRAM probably cut the per-bit cost by a factor of four compared with systems like the Atari 2600.  Incidentally, the reason the Atari 400 was able to include such a generous amount of memory compared with e.g. the VIC-20 is that the Atari 400 used DRAM while the VIC-20 used static RAM.

Comment: Indeed. The cost difference between SRAM and DRAM persists to this day, and many machines like Apple II employed smart hardware tricks in order to be able to use the cheaper DRAM chips until separate memory controller chips became common.

Comment: @jpa: The cost difference persists, but there are many kinds of DRAM and some variations in SRAM as well.  In 1976, there were only two practical forms of RAM memory whose price per byte was within an order of magnitude of each other.  From what I understand, a RAM built out of bipolar chips could offer better performance than a MOS-based RAM, but I think a 64-bit bipolar RAM cost as much as a 1024-bit static RAM.